# How to display time difference in human readable form in Yii2 (for example 2 days ago)?

Tags: yii2

Does anyone who know how to count date time for notification ..for example "a few ago" or just now like this:

[image]

I hope anyone can help me to solve this problem:

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:;">
        <span class="time">3 mins</span>
        <span class="details">
        <span class="label label-sm label-icon label-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
        </span> Server #12 overloaded. </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the formatting. You can achieve your desired result with javascript or back end depending on your requirements. You should have a go, and come back if you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 14):

Use the [build-in formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html) with the *relative time* format:

```
<?php echo Yii::$app->formatter->format($timeOfEvent, 'relativeTime') ?>
```

Comment: can you explain more...i need to understand that code...this $timeOfEvent for what...and relativeTime ....and can i know the function for $timeOfEvent...actually i count the no of user based their created time..

Comment: @zack `$timeOfEvent` is a variable containing the time at which an event occured.  So if you want to show a relative value for the time of creation, the creation time is what you would pass in here.

Comment: can you give example for $timeOfEvent

Comment: @zack: anything that describes a time: Possible values include a unix timestamp (e.g. 1450969989),  a DateTime object, or a string [which can be converted to a time](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) (e.g. a MySQL TIMESTAMP string, like `2015-10-28 12:22:33`).

Comment: can i know how to get date from another model....example from customer table that contain attribute for date

Comment: @zack that would require detailed knowledge of your application.  Please refer to the respective Yii documentation or ask a separate question for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple function for evaluate the diff between two date and format them properly depending of the magnitude of diff (min, hour, day, week..)

```
 public function notifyDate($myStartDate) {

 $datediff = $now - $myStartDate;
 if ($datediff < (60*60)) {  // Minutes
   return floor($datediff/(60*60*24)) . " Minutes ago ";
 }
 if ($datediff < (60*60*24)) {  // Hours
   return floor($datediff/(60*60*24)) . " Hours ago ";
 }
 // this  return the number of day
 return  floor($datediff/(60*60*24)) ;

 }
```

and call this function in you notification bar

```
<li>
     <a href="javascript:;">
          <span class="time"><?php echo notifyDate($myStartDate); ?></span>
               <span class="details">
                   <span class="label label-sm label-icon label-danger">
                        <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
                </span> Server #12 overloaded. 
           </span>

      </a>

</li>
```